# video tag not working in desktop firefox, but work on mobile firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have two video tag, one work fine but second give me error,

`no video with supported format and mime`.

This is First video tag. Which work fine and take this e.g from [This Link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

```
<video loop controls class="popvideo">
    <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

Second video tag which is not working on desktop but work in android firefox version, and throw me error.

```
<video class="popvideo" loop controls id="v1">
    <source src="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/771965608854446080/vid/480x360/J-cvquAduyhPHJmg.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'">
    <!--<source src="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/771965608854446080/vid/480x360/J-cvquAduyhPHJmg.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
if i do this too nothing happen, i still get error-->


    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

i have add this to my .haccess but none helped.

`AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/x-flv flv`

So my question is why this is happening? if you will say [Fire fox don't support mp4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) then i will tell first example is taken form respected site only.

Comment: _"Second video tag which is not working on desktop"_ which desktop did you test? In fact both links work for me as tested now on **Win 7** with **Firefox 47.0.1**. Use the link as shown in @RachelGallen's correct **Answer**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second source that you commented out that you said "also doesn't work" has an error in it - If you look at it, there's a semi-colon before the quotes, after the mp4. When you remove the semi-colon, your video plays fine.
It then becomes:

```html
<video class="popvideo" loop controls id="v1">
      <source src="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/771965608854446080/vid/480x360/J-cvquAduyhPHJmg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

The 'No video with supported format or mime type" error was logged as a known bug with firefox a long time ago, and fixes were suggested and it is marked as fully resolved. Have you updated to the latest desktop version? The bug was [990623](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=990623)  - the [solutions suggested](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/992637) were to reload (after updating ff),  by pressing ctrl+shift +r and if that didn't work, to just right click on the video and choose 'View Video', and that would play the video. The ultimate solution is to restore Firefox, it seems the issue was caused primarily by conflicts with add-ons etc. It's not ideal, because you'll have to re-install any add ons but it works (see screenshot)

So to sum up, your issue is not the video itself, it's more a firefox issue...

Hope this helps

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4geegk5/)

[image: RUNNING ON FF AFTER 'RESTORE FIREFOX']

Comment: for back up, you should really add ogg/webm formats however - there are converters available online

Comment: to restore/refresh firefox go to to the '?' icon and click on Firefox help: it should bring you to this page https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

Answer (score 1):

Check your `type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'"` attributes from [Video Codecs](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters)

```
<source src="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/771965608854446080/vid/480x360/J-cvquAduyhPHJmg.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'">
```

Check all browser support for HTML-5 video [HTML 5 Video - Browser Support](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I assume it means the codec which is required to decode (and thus play) the video is available on the phone, but not on your desktop. Try another video or encode yours with an open source codec which supported by Firefox out of the box.

Also, note that the filename extension is practically meaningless for videos - it is merely a container format. The actual encoding of the contents in the container is what matters - and it, in turn can vary wildly.